# how to change one dropdown values to be changed while selecting other dropdown in D3, like country, state, city

Tags: d3.js

I wanna do some tricks with D3, that I need to change the dropdown list values changed while selecting other dropdown list. This is not tedious in jquery and programming languages, but I want to do using D3.js.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your `select` element is:

```
<select id='grouping'>
....
</select>
```

What you need to do is add a listener to pend for changes on this element. If your function that draws the SVG chart is called `draw`, then the only thing you need to do is add this line at the end of your script:

```
d3.select("#grouping").on("change", draw);
```

Is this helping at all?